# Subgroups of an infinite group with a given index

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group and $\alpha$ a cardinal number with $\aleph_0\leq \alpha\leq |G|$. Is there a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $|G:H|=\alpha$ (what about $|H|=\alpha$)?

Comment: Getting $|H|=\alpha$ is easy; just select $\alpha$ elements of $G$ to generate $H$. Not sure about the question of controlling the index though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are groups of cardinality $\aleph_1$ (the particular group is an instance of a Jonsson group) that only have countable proper subgroups, so index of a subgroup group is either $\aleph_1$ or $1$ (no subgroup of index $\aleph_0$).

This is done in a paper of Shelah: *On a problem of Kurosh, Jonsson groups, and applications*.

Comment: I was wondering whether something like this existed; I'll have to look at that paper. This is what I was really wondering, and the paper might answer my question: for arbitrary infinite $\alpha$, does there exist a group of order $\alpha$ whose proper subgroups all have strictly smaller cardinality?

Comment: In the case $\alpha = \aleph_0$, the group of $(p^n)$-th roots of unity fits the bill.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein The paper proves that there are Johnsson groups of cardinality $\aleph_1$, and of cardinality $\lambda^+$ when $\lambda^+=2^\lambda$. I am not sure if there is a reason why it could not be for arbitrary cardinalities though (maybe there is a general obstruction).

Comment: I could not access the paper from home, but your last comment seems to suggest that whether it actually has cardinality $\aleph_1$ depends on the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein For a somewhat more weird example of a countable one, we can take the Tarski monster.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Actually for the $\aleph_1$ case it does not depend on the continuum hypothesis. (It does not rely on whether or not $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$)

Comment: In remark towards the end of the paper, Shelah says that it could be done with $\aleph_2$ (without CH), but for further $\aleph_n$ the situation not clear. @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft re the Tarski monster...  Good to know that's a thing.