# Subgroups of an infinite abelian group with a given index

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

This is followed by the question: [Subgroups of an infinite group with a given index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678854/subgroups-of-an-infinite-group-with-a-given-index) (with a  counterexample of non-abelian groups). Now, the question is:

Let $G$ be an *infinite abelian group* and $\alpha$ a cardinal number with $\aleph_0\leq \alpha\leq |G|$. Is there a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $|G:H|=\alpha$ ?

Comment: Did you check "Abelian Groups", by L.Fuchs? It is a bit dated but contains wealth of information.

Comment: No. I don't have this book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if $G$ is countable, you just take $H$ to be the trivial subgroup of $G$, it will have countably infinite index. Thus, I assume that $G$ is uncountable of cardinality $A$. Then by

W. R. Scott, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 5, No. 1 (1954), pp. 19-22,

*The Number of Subgroups of Given Index in Nondenumerable Abelian Groups*

the group $G$ contains $2^A$ subgroups of every index $\alpha$, 
$$
\aleph_0\leq \alpha\leq |G|. 
$$